# How Do I Download 30,000 Images Using Google Drive API?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests, google-drive-api

I need to download 30,000 images using the Google Drive API (I have all of their `file_id`s saved locally) so that I can upload them to AWS S3, but after only 20-30 image requests to the API, I get a 403 error, which means I'm exceeding the API Quota (1,000 requests per 100sec per user - not sure how I'm exceeding it but that's besides the point). My code sleeps for 2 seconds between each request and I still get this error. I need to download and upload these files in a reasonable amount of time, any suggestions?

Comment: Hi there, could you show us your current code, as well as the stack trace for the error, where it is occurring and so on. I am not personally able to answer your question but I am sure having the above mentioned information will help those people who are trying to answer you. Please take a look here for further information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which library are you using to get the request. But as per my understanding urlopen will raise an HTTPError for those it can’t handle like `‘403’ (request forbidden).

Reference - [List of Errors](https://docs.python.org/3.1/howto/urllib2.html#error-codes)

```
403: ('Forbidden',
      'Request forbidden -- authorization will not help').
```

Instead you can use - [urlretrieve()](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)

Sharing a small code sample : -

```
import urllib.request
url = 'http://example.com/'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read()      # a `bytes` object
text = data.decode('utf-8') # a `str`; this step can't be used if data is binary
```

Answer (score 0):

- Downloading images with Drive API will count as one request per image, so can easily surpass the quota limit
- Luckily there is a workaround - **you can use [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)** which allows you to download up to 100 images with one request.
- The documentaiton provides [samples for implementation in Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#using-client-libraries).
- Btw., you can check your [quota usage](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_your_quota) in your GCP console.